# How to add a static file in the pdf file using xhtml2pdf?

Tags: python, html, templates, xhtml2pdf

I am trying add a static image which is already there in my folder in my pdf file using `xhtml2pdf`.

My `app.py` looks like this.

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from pathlib import Path

output_filename = "output.pdf"
source_html = Path('template.html').read_text()
print(source_html)

result_file = open(output_filename, "w+b")

pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(
    source_html,
    dest=result_file)
result_file.close()
```

And my `template.html` looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Title of the document.</h1>
    <img src="img/logo.png" />
  </body>
</html>
```

My logo.png lies in the `img` folder along the side of `app.py`.

```
app.py
img/
   logo.png
template.html
```

When I run

```
python app.py
```

This do generate the pdf file, however the image is missing. And it gives me the following error.

```
Extract data form local file
Need a valid file name!
'<img src="img/logo.png"/>'
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It worked on Alpine 3.12.  After the Alpine has upgraded to 3.16, I experienced the same error.  I have to make the png file readable to everyone by `chmod 444 img/logo.png`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).